# VirtualView node must not be the root node

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

When I call **showDialog** function in my app, in the log of my app there will appear many many "**E/AccessibilityBridge(22374): VirtualView node must not be the root node.**" errors.

This error doesn't affect to my app, it works well but I wanted to solve this issue

Comment: What's your flutter version? this is a known issue on [flutter#44635](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44635).

Comment: Try Upgrading Flutter using `flutter upgrade`.

Comment: @Tokenyet **Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76**